# Chropath is installed on Firefox but not able to see it's tab in devtools panel

Tags: selenium, chropath

Chropath is installed on Firefox but not able to see it's tab in devtools panel.
What should I need to do
I have uninstalled and installed many times and restarted the browser as well
Kindly help

Comment: Try with latest versions of Firefox and Chropath, also provide details of your OS. If it is Windows, give it a try by first uninstalling Firefox, restarting the machine and then install Firefox and Chropath both.

Answer (score 0):

ChroPath used to show as different tab (not sidebar like in chrome) in Firefox developer tools. Currently ChroPath functionality is different in Chrome and Firefox. Soon ChroPath will have same functionality in Chrome and Firefox both.

[image: ChroPath in Firefox developer tools]

Comment: Now ChroPath is available in Sidebar same as in Chrome.